# Sharepoint list in Preview Pane but without ECB menu (context menu)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

This is doing my head in...

I have a list, which I display in Preview Pane so that users can easily click through the list. But the problem is that the ECB menu appears, so users can edit the list.

I want to achieve the Preview Pane, with the linked items, but without the ECB menu altogether.

Unfortunately I have no permissions to the site to alter any js files etc, but I can edit the aspx page where my list is displayed.

Can anyone please help, the preview pane looks great, but I need it without the ECB menu alongside any of the records columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following script to hide the ECB menu to the page where the list is being displayed:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("div.s4-ctx").hide();

});  
</script>
```

-Open the page in sharepoint designer.

-search for the script tag.

-Place it as follows within the script tag. And the reference to jquery outside the script tag.
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Where do I add this script?

Comment: Where do I add this?

Comment: Where do I add this script? I have sharepoint designer open and using a new aspx page with inserted dataview. Where do I add the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your view XML *(Using SharePoint Designer)* find the column in your **ViewFields** where the menu is showing up and change the ListMenuItem attribute of the **FieldRef** element to FALSE:

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="SomeField1" ListMenuItem="FALSE" />
    <FieldRef Name="SomeField2"/>
    <FieldRef Name="SomeField3"/>
</ViewFields>
```